# PHP Array to jQuery array with JSON. ($.post, parseJSON, json_encode)

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to get a php file setup to return the results of a MySQL database query from a jQuery AJAX call. The returned results **will be an array**.  I have a very basic start where I am just getting some basic data back and forth to and from the php file, but am stuck with some basic syntax issues:

The PHP code:

```
$arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);  
echo json_encode($arr);
```

The jQuery code:

```
$.post("dbFile.php", str, function(theResponse){
     alert('the response: ' + theResponse);
     var obj = $.parseJSON(theResponse);
     alert(obj.a);
```

I can print out obj.a, obj.b, obj.c... no problem.  The problem is I will be incrementing a counter as I increment through the MySQL results.  So, the array does not use letters, it uses numbers:

```
$arr[$i] = mysqlresults ... $i++;
```

So, in the JavaScript/jQuery I have an object (not an array). I can print out obj.a for example, but I can not print out obj.2 (for example). In other words, if I replace the letters with numbers in the php array, I don't know how to print them out in JavaScript/jQuery.  Can I change the object that parseJSON returns into an array somehow (so that I can cycle through it)?

Comment: If you send the result with `echo json_encode(array_values($arr));` it will be guaranteed to be an ordinary (continuously indexed) Javascript array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
alert(obj['a']);
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) for more info.

Answer (score 5):

Use the array access syntax:

```
alert(obj[42]);
```